# How to split a string without given delimeter in Panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dfcolumn = [PUEF2CarmenXFc034DpEd, PUEF2BalulanFc034CamH, CARF1BalulanFc013Baca, ...]
```

My output should be:

```
dfnewcolumn1 = [PUEF2, PUEF2 , CARF1]
dfnewcolumn2 = [CarmenXFc034DpEd, BalulanFc034CamH, BalulanFc013Baca]
```

Comment: well, what defines how these strings should be split?  Even a human can't split your strings unless you say what the condition is

Comment: i recommend to close this question unless we have enough information to answer it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your split criteria is by fixed number of characters (e.g. 5 here), you can use:

```
df['dfnewcolumn1'] = df['dfcolumn'].str[:5]
df['dfnewcolumn2'] = df['dfcolumn'].str[5:]
```

Result:

```
                dfcolumn dfnewcolumn1      dfnewcolumn2
0  PUEF2CarmenXFc034DpEd        PUEF2  CarmenXFc034DpEd
1  PUEF2BalulanFc034CamH        PUEF2  BalulanFc034CamH
2  CARF1BalulanFc013Baca        CARF1  BalulanFc013Baca
```

If your split criteria is by the first digit in the string, you can use:

```
df[['dfnewcolumn1', 'dfnewcolumnX']] = df['dfcolumn'].str.split(r'(?<=\d)\D', n=1, expand=True)
df[['dfnewcolumnX', 'dfnewcolumn2']] = df['dfcolumn'].str.split(r'\D*\d', n=1, expand=True)
df = df.drop(columns='dfnewcolumnX')
```

Using the following modified original data with more test cases:

```
                 dfcolumn
0   PUEF2CarmenXFc034DpEd
1   PUEF2BalulanFc034CamH
2   CARF1BalulanFc013Baca
3    CAF1BalulanFc013Baca
4  PUEFA2BalulanFc034CamH
```

Run code:

```
df[['dfnewcolumn1', 'dfnewcolumnX']] = df['dfcolumn'].str.split(r'(?<=\d)\D', n=1, expand=True)
df[['dfnewcolumnX', 'dfnewcolumn2']] = df['dfcolumn'].str.split(r'\D*\d', n=1, expand=True)
df = df.drop(columns='dfnewcolumnX')
```

Result:

```
                 dfcolumn dfnewcolumn1      dfnewcolumn2
0   PUEF2CarmenXFc034DpEd        PUEF2  CarmenXFc034DpEd
1   PUEF2BalulanFc034CamH        PUEF2  BalulanFc034CamH
2   CARF1BalulanFc013Baca        CARF1  BalulanFc013Baca
3    CAF1BalulanFc013Baca         CAF1  BalulanFc013Baca
4  PUEFA2BalulanFc034CamH       PUEFA2  BalulanFc034CamH
```

Comment: Thank you, @SeaBean. This code is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Pati  So why do you choose another answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your prefix consists of a sequence of alphabets followed by a sequence of digits, which both have variable length. Then a regex split function can be constructed and applied on each cell.

## Solution

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["dfcolumn"] = ["PUEF2CarmenXFc034DpEd", "PUEF2BalulanFc034CamH", "CARF1BalulanFc013Baca"]

def f_split(s: str):
    """Split two part by regex"""
    # alphabet(s) followed by digit(s)
    o = re.match(r"^([A-Za-z]+\d+)(.*)$", s)
    # may add exception handling here if there is no match
    return o.group(1), o.group(2)

df[["dfnewcolumn1", "dfnewcolumn2"]] = df["dfcolumn"].apply(f_split).to_list()
```

Note the `.to_list()` to convert tuples into lists, which is required for the new column assignment to work.

## Result

```
print(df)
                dfcolumn dfnewcolumn1      dfnewcolumn2
0  PUEF2CarmenXFc034DpEd        PUEF2  CarmenXFc034DpEd
1  PUEF2BalulanFc034CamH        PUEF2  BalulanFc034CamH
2  CARF1BalulanFc013Baca        CARF1  BalulanFc013Baca
```

Comment: without knowing what really is needed, i would have just given `[:5], [5:]` as the split. Well, i am not sure if the format in the regex is always the case. I don't see enough information in the question to decide this

Answer (score 0):

Hoe about this compact solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"original": ["PUEF2CarmenXFc034DpEd", "PUEF2BalulanFc034CamH", "CARF1BalulanFc013Baca"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.original.str.split(r"(\d)", n=1).to_list(), columns=["part1", "separator", "part2"])
df2.part1 = df2.part1 + df2.separator.astype(str)
df2

   part1 separator             part2
0  PUEF2         2  CarmenXFc034DpEd
1  PUEF2         2  BalulanFc034CamH
2  CARF1         1  BalulanFc013Baca
```

I use:

- `Series.str.split` with a regex pattern and a kwarg to specify that it should only split  on the first match.
- in th regex pattern, I use a group (the round braces in `(\d)`) to capture the separating character
- `to_list()` to output the split as a list of lists
- DataFrame constructor to build a new DataFrame from that list
- string concat of two columns